# Working with Android and Jsoup parsing a table to a certain element

Tags: android, html, jsoup

The problem I am having is that I am trying to parse this [website](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/tables/article.php/3479851) but I am getting [this](http://postimg.org/image/8iaf6quxf/)error . I am new to Jsoup and not quite sure whats making the error. Is there a way to stop parsing on certain element like if i want it to stop on first instance of Bobby? (row : Cindy : Mike : Bobby). Thanks in advance!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class tableScreen extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.table);
        takeTable();
    }

    public static int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    public void takeTable()
    {
        Document doc = null;

        if (SDK_INT >= 10) 
        {
            ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
        }
        try{
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/tables/article.php/3479851").get();

        System.out.println("1");
        Element containingDiv = doc.select(".body").first();

        System.out.println("2");
            Elements table = containingDiv.select("table");
            System.out.println("3");
            Elements rows = table.select("tr");
            System.out.println("4");
            for (Element row : rows)
            {

                System.out.println("row: "+row.child(0).text()+" : "+row.child(1).text()+" : "+ row.child(2).text());

            }
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }


}
```

Comment: OK guys I manage to fix it ,
      
        Element containingDiv = doc.select("table").first();
        
        Elements table = containingDiv.select("tbody");
that's it.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and *accept* it, so others can see it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

OK guys I manage to fix it ,

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/tables/article.php/3479851").get();
Element containingDiv = doc.select("table").first();
Elements table = containingDiv.select("tbody");
Elements rows = table.select("tr");
```